# Why is my code give different numbers for the same word?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
restart = 'y'
while (True):
    sentence = input("What is your sentence?: ")
    sentence_split = sentence.split()
    lowersen=(sentence.lower())
    print(lowersen)
    sentence2 = [0]
    for count, i in enumerate(sentence_split):
        if sentence_split.count(i) < 2:
            sentence2.append(max(sentence2) + 1)
        else:
            sentence2.append(sentence_split.index(i) +1)
    sentence2.remove(0)
    print(sentence2)
    restart = input("would you like restart the programme y/n?").lower()
    if (restart == "n"):
            print ("programme terminated")
            break
    elif (restart == "y"):
        pass
    else:
        print ("Please enter y or n")
```

Line 4 converts all words in the input sentence into lowercase and line 5 displays that on the page. However, words are given different numbers if they are firstly input in a different format. For example, I trialed the code and this is what is displayed:

**What is your sentence?:** Hello there hello

**hello there hello**

**[1, 2, 3]**

**would you like restart the programme y/n?** n

**programme terminated**

As you can see, because the first "Hello" has a capital, it is assigned a different number to the second one which does not, even though they are supposedly both converted into lower case. Why is this? I can't seem to find a fault, so I need another pair of eyes to help.

Comment: You're lowercasing after you've already split. Try `sentence_split = sentence.lower().split()` and removing the `lowersen` thing.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. Such a simple mistake. Thank you.

Comment: @Milkiemash if a question is answered - accept and/or vote for the answer(s) that helped you - there's no need to add `[Answered]` to the title of your question - thanks.

Comment: @JonClements I know. However, the answer is in the comments (seen above), and therefore I cannot accept it as an answer and had to write it in the title to stop people from responding.

Answer (score 0):

You do `lowersen=(sentence.lower())` and afterwards you never use that value of lowersen, so either use the value lowersen like:

```
sentence = input("What is your sentence?: ")
lowersen=(sentence.lower())
sentence_split = lowersen.split()
```

or a easy oneliner and omit lowersen altogether:

```
sentence_split = sentence.lower().split()
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by ChatterOne in the comments of this post, the code did not work as it was lowercasing after the sentence was split:

```
sentence_split = sentence.split()
lowersen=(sentence.lower())
```

whereas it needed to be done before hand.

Therefore, the code:

```
sentence_split = sentence.split()
lowersen=(sentence.lower())
print(lowersen)
```

needs to be changed to:

```
sentence_split = sentence.lower().split()
print(sentence.lower())
```